# Calculating date of heliacal rising of well know stars using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to astronomy, and would like to find a way to calculate the date of the heliacal rising of well know stars form a given location using javascript, so that the dates can be rendered in a table on  a web page.

Are there any existing javascript libraries that will allow me to do this? And if so how would I go about using said library to achieve my objective?

Comment: https://barrycarter.github.io/pages/HELIACAL/

Comment: Well that nails it, thank you very much! You should have posted it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: I knew I felt a sense of deja vu. It turns out I wrote that code to answer this duplicate question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25677/when-does-a-star-rise-with-the-sun/34786#34786